# RegEx Files with .php .html and without dot (folder)

Tags: regex, apache2

can someone help me writing an RegEx for Apache Mod Rewrite?
i wannt do select all with .html and .php on the and, and all without dots (folders)

> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .(html|php)$

This is what i have at the moment, so i need to add something like "or doesn't contain any ."

:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/.*(\.(html|php))?/`

I think that would of select php and html files along folders. Good Luck

Comment: mh, it doesn't select folders at al, i use this script right now: http://pastebin.com/4DTctgqR

Comment: I dont know how Apache's Regex engine work, but it should of selected folders... i am going to test it on my own to see :p. EDIT: Can i see an output of Apache's file/directory listing?

Comment: I mean. How apache lists directories, in other words... what is that regex above being matched into?

Comment: i don't have a clue what you mean :D but this is my directory: http://www.myimg.de/?img=dir220e5.png and if i type in such as "localhost/folder" it should foreward to index.php?s=folder, but it throw me an 404. sorry for my bad english :/

Comment: What i mean is: Can you access the string into which Apache lists the files? It has to be one so the regex string can be executed against it.

Comment: ahhh. i dont know. i use :"%{REQUEST_URI}" which is all .. "http://localhost/folder" i guess.

Comment: Then i dont know how can i help you more :/ Maybe this will help: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: ahh! found the bug. i used $ on the end of the RewriteCond and i had to use ?... don't know their meaning, but i'm lucky :D

Comment: Cool... but its weird... $ makes the regex pattern match at the end of line... it would be advisable unless all of the files are separated by spaces instead of line breaks... anyways, im happy i managed to help you. Good luck